# Sidekiq processing and javascript push notifications

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq, faye

I have some long running tasks that i process with Sidekiq/Redis in the background. When completed, I'd like to give the user a notification that it is complete.

I'm probably going to use Faye for the pub/sub.

How will I know when a Sidekiq process is completed, and where should I handle it (and push to Faye) in my app?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? I'm working on something similar and I need to decide if it's best to implement it using Faye or ActionController::live

Comment: Hi. I did end up using Faye (had problems with the ruby version, so im using the nodejs one). Whenever my code is complete, I use the Curb gem to send off data to Faye.